Intersections between cubic polynomial and circle
The problem I want to solve is this: 
For monic cubic polynomial $f(x)$, define $g(t)$ as the number of distinct intersections between the graph $y=f(x)$ and $x^2+y^2=t^2$. In other words, $g(t)$ is the number of distinct solutions of $d(x)=t^2$, where $d(x)=x^2+\{f(x)\}^2$.
$g(t)$ should satisfy two conditions:

$g(t)$ is even for every $t>0$
there exists $t>0$ where $g(t)=6$

Prove that $f(x)$ is an odd function.

I managed to work out the followings:

$f(x)$ should have a form $f(x)=x(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a<0<b$.
$d(x)$ should have three local minimums and two local maximums in total. $x=0$ is always local minimum of $d(x)$.
If we deonte $x = p, x = q$ as two local minimums of $d(x)$, then $d(p) = d(q) $
If we deonte $x = r, x = s$ as two local maximums of $d(x)$, then $d(r) = d(s) $
If $a+b>0$ and $p+q>0$, contradiction occurs

My approach is to assume that $a+b>0$ and finding a contradiction. I tried to find inequalities between $d(p), d(q)$ or $d(r), d(s)$, but I couldn't figure it out.
